# downloadProgress block in downloadTaskWithRequest is not called under AFNetworking 3.1.0 When downloading a gzip file

Tags: ios, objective-c, amazon-s3, gzip, afnetworking-3

I'm using AFNetworking 3.1.0 to download some pdfs from AWS S3. The only issue is that when the file is gzipped, the download progress block is not getting called.

```
NSURLSessionConfiguration *configuration = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
AFURLSessionManager *manager = [[AFURLSessionManager alloc] initWithSessionConfiguration:configuration];

NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://s3.amazonaws.com/awdtest/fullzip.pdf"];
NSURLRequest *request1 = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:URL];

NSURLSessionDownloadTask *downloadTask1 = [manager downloadTaskWithRequest:request1 progress:^(NSProgress * _Nonnull downloadProgress)
{
    NSLog(@"Progress: %f", downloadProgress.fractionCompleted);
} destination:^NSURL *(NSURL *targetPath, NSURLResponse *response)
{
    NSURL *documentsDirectoryURL = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory inDomain:NSUserDomainMask appropriateForURL:nil create:NO error:nil];
    return [documentsDirectoryURL URLByAppendingPathComponent:[response suggestedFilename]];
} completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSURL *filePath, NSError *error)
{
    NSLog(@"File downloaded to: %@", filePath);
}];
[downloadTask1 resume];
```

Response headers:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
x-amz-id-2: CW06YcgIycOHZQy8bCJrT3aNfhatM9pty1mOjgYHumjCxRmNAQ+jhJHRQwl7mDIaQeTHI0fyrnU=
x-amz-request-id: 105E010DECC91897
Date: Sat, 14 May 2016 09:26:38 GMT
Content-Encoding: gzip
Last-Modified: Sat, 14 May 2016 09:21:29 GMT
ETag: "88bbe0b318bf11dd56a31176d3384e78"
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Type: application/pdf
Content-Length: 1243325
Server: AmazonS3
```

the progress block gets called if I use a non gzipped file: https://s3.amazonaws.com/awdtest/full.pdf

Response headers:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
x-amz-id-2: gFOVfhheaMdeJOBb+7H8oaXjLLeOqlQl616XnYx6C2Gj7PBVLKZ9kMIN2fJOrGBcSgQ/7nbQOc0=
x-amz-request-id: 26669D9B576E300A
Date: Sat, 14 May 2016 09:54:58 GMT
Last-Modified: Fri, 16 May 2014 05:42:35 GMT
ETag: "6f16d7e09023ce8b50fd67abba7825c4"
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Type: application/pdf
Content-Length: 1411131
Server: AmazonS3
```

I would appreciate any help.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that when the transmission is gzipped, the underlying `NSURLSession` doesn't know the size of the transmission, so while it calls the progress delegate method with updates, the expected size is unknown. Thus, percent-complete is unknown and it's therefore hard to update the `NSProgress`.

You can call `setDownloadTaskDidWriteDataBlock` block, though, and get the count of bytes as they come in, at the very least. You'll see that the `totalBytesExpectedToWrite` is negative (i.e. `NSURLResponseUnknownLength`), indicating that it doesn't know the number of bytes expected:

```
NSURLSessionDownloadTask *downloadTask1 = [manager downloadTaskWithRequest:request1 progress:^(NSProgress * _Nonnull downloadProgress) {
    NSLog(@"Progress: %f", downloadProgress.fractionCompleted);
} destination:^NSURL *(NSURL *targetPath, NSURLResponse *response) {
    NSURL *documentsDirectoryURL = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory inDomain:NSUserDomainMask appropriateForURL:nil create:NO error:nil];
    return [documentsDirectoryURL URLByAppendingPathComponent:[response suggestedFilename]];
} completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSURL *filePath, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"File downloaded to: %@", filePath);
}];

[manager setDownloadTaskDidWriteDataBlock:^(NSURLSession *session, NSURLSessionDownloadTask *downloadTask, int64_t bytesWritten, int64_t totalBytesWritten, int64_t totalBytesExpectedToWrite) {
    NSLog(@"setDownloadTaskDidWriteDataBlock: %lld %lld %lld", bytesWritten, totalBytesWritten, totalBytesExpectedToWrite);
}];

[downloadTask1 resume];
```

That yields:

```
2016-05-27 15:43:21.987 MyApp[41366:3034687] setDownloadTaskDidWriteDataBlock: 25510 25510 -1
2016-05-27 15:43:22.086 MyApp[41366:3034654] setDownloadTaskDidWriteDataBlock: 18934 44444 -1
2016-05-27 15:43:22.122 MyApp[41366:3034647] setDownloadTaskDidWriteDataBlock: 19184 63628 -1
...
2016-05-27 15:43:22.884 MyApp[41366:3034698] setDownloadTaskDidWriteDataBlock: 20742 1397325 -1
2016-05-27 15:43:22.885 MyApp[41366:3034637] setDownloadTaskDidWriteDataBlock: 13806 1411131 -1
2016-05-27 15:43:23.018 MyApp[41366:3034381] File downloaded to: file:///Users/.../D8735AFD-77F4-4496-B358-162467169C96/Documents/fullzip.pdf
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Content-Length is provided by the server as one of the response headers, therefore it should use that to calculate the progress, correct?

Comment: You would have thunk, but if you look at the `Content-Length` header for `fullzip.pdf`, it is `1243325` (presumably the size of gzipped transmission), but if you watch it in the `downloadTaskDidWriteDataBlock`, you'll see the total bytes was `1411131` (the size after gunzipping). It's a well known problem with `Content-Encoding` of `gzip`. Historically we could set `Accept-Encoding` to force it to not `gzip` regardless of what the server was doing, but that doesn't appear to work here.

Comment: FYI, I tested this on another server, and setting `Accept-Encoding` in the request does turn off `gzip`. It looks like your URL is not observing `Accept-Encoding`. I don't even know if you want to turn off gzip (presumably slowing the request for the sake of progress updates).